# R: Histogram with large data set

Tags: r, graph, graphics, histogram, large-data

**Goal**

From the data.frame `d`, I am trying to make a histogram of the column `cMPerSite` weighted by `bpInPiece`. In other words, `bpInPiece` is the number of observations at each `cMPerSite` value.

The Y-axis should represent densities and the X-axis should be on a log scale.

**Attempts**

I could do something like (which could be improved by pre-allocating the memory size for `x`).

```
x = c()
for (row in 1:nrow(d))
{
    x = c(x, rep(d$cMPerSite[row],d$bpInPiece[row]))
}
hist(x,breaks=100, freq=FALSE)
```

[image]

but this becomes completely impractical when there is too much data (I have about 10 millions rows in my full data set) because `x` becomes too large to be stored in the RAM. Also, putting the X-axis in log scale is, I think, necessarily a bit of a mess.

Alternatively, I would have thought I could do

```
ggplot(d) + geom_histogram(aes(x = cMPerSite, y=bpInPiece), stat="identity") + scale_x_log10() + theme_classic(25)
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad
```

[image]

but, for some reason I do not understand, nothing gets displayed. Also, I am not sure how to put the Y-axis in density rather than count.

I suppose the bin size should vary logarithmically as the X-axis varies but that's confuses me as it would result in bins gathering an "artificial" high number of observations. Not sure how histograms are typically displayed with log scale X axis. Note that `ggplot(d) + geom_histogram(aes(x = cMPerSite, y=bpInPiece), stat="identity")` does not display anything either so the problem is not only a question of log scale on the X-axis.

**Can you help me to make this histogram?**

**Subset of my data**

```
structure(list(chrom = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), end = c(241608, 
612298, 715797, 956634, 983330, 1190613, 1236417, 1330208, 1391915, 
1464000, 1911436, 1913462, 2092038, 2169783, 2354812, 2363639, 
2544241, 2551672, 2575287, 2589721, 2659117, 2884565, 3037319, 
3100967, 3152276, 4319658, 4335072, 6301896, 6550219, 6596684, 
7132319, 7435267, 7469158, 7604030, 7937619, 8131876, 9359659, 
9598491, 9945959, 10262757, 10392172, 10646861, 10816847, 11094415, 
11360199, 11964985, 12220179, 12222166, 12389943), cMInPiece = c(0, 
1e-07, 1e-07, 0.7118558, 9.99999999473644e-08, 0.9540829, 9.99999998363421e-08, 
0.4967211, 1.244988, 0.2137991, 8.808171, 0.500545200000001, 
1.5721302, 1.6856566, 2.2552469, 1.0000000116861e-07, 2.6973586, 
0.355113100000001, 0.355233800000001, 1.0000000116861e-07, 1.4903822, 
2.8174978, 1.0000000116861e-07, 0.355231, 1.0000000116861e-07, 
8.2735924, 0.425817699999996, 6.4568106, 0.372779399999999, 0.363684999999997, 
0.181640399999999, 0.177473599999999, 1.0000000116861e-07, 0.177463800000005, 
0.355294099999995, 1.0000000116861e-07, 1.6101482, 1.0000000116861e-07, 
0.533477099999999, 0.355287800000006, 9.99999940631824e-08, 1.0000000116861e-07, 
1.0000000116861e-07, 1.0000000116861e-07, 1.0000000116861e-07, 
1.0000000116861e-07, 9.99999940631824e-08, 1.0000000116861e-07, 
1.0000000116861e-07), bpInPiece = c(241608, 370690, 103499, 240837, 
26696, 207283, 45804, 93791, 61707, 72085, 447436, 2026, 178576, 
77745, 185029, 8827, 180602, 7431, 23615, 14434, 69396, 225448, 
152754, 63648, 51309, 1167382, 15414, 1966824, 248323, 46465, 
535635, 302948, 33891, 134872, 333589, 194257, 1227783, 238832, 
347468, 316798, 129415, 254689, 169986, 277568, 265784, 604786, 
255194, 1987, 167777), cMPerSite = c(1e-16, 2.69767190914241e-13, 
9.66192910076426e-13, 2.95575762860358e-06, 3.74587953054257e-12, 
4.60280341369046e-06, 2.18321543612659e-12, 5.29604226418313e-06, 
2.01757985317711e-05, 2.96593049871679e-06, 1.96858790977928e-05, 
0.000247060809476802, 8.80370374518411e-06, 2.16818650717088e-05, 
1.21886131363192e-05, 1.13288774406491e-11, 1.49353750235324e-05, 
4.77880635176962e-05, 1.50427186110523e-05, 6.92808654348135e-12, 
2.14764856764078e-05, 1.24973288740641e-05, 6.54647349127419e-13, 
5.58118086978381e-06, 1.94897583598608e-12, 7.08730509807415e-06, 
2.76253860127155e-05, 3.28286140498591e-06, 1.50118756619403e-06, 
7.82707414182711e-06, 3.39112268615754e-07, 5.85821989252278e-07, 
2.95063589650969e-12, 1.31579423453352e-06, 1.06506539484214e-06, 
5.14781970114898e-13, 1.31142734506016e-06, 4.18704366117646e-13, 
1.53532728193675e-06, 1.1214963478305e-06, 7.72707909154135e-13, 
3.92635728942395e-13, 5.88283747888707e-13, 3.60272081683082e-13, 
3.76245376578762e-13, 1.65347744770232e-13, 3.91858719496471e-13, 
5.03271269092148e-11, 5.96029260080999e-13)), .Names = c("chrom", 
"end", "cMInPiece", "bpInPiece", "cMPerSite"), row.names = c(NA, 
-49L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You're trying to grow `x` within that `for loop` which is extremely inefficient. More info here http://r-statistics.co/Strategies-To-Improve-And-Speedup-R-Code.html & http://winvector.github.io/Accumulation/

Comment: What is preferred bin size? log10 == 1? Do you want to sum `bpInPiece`? Or count each occurrence of `bpInPiece`?

Comment: @CPak I suppose the bin size should vary logarithmically as the X-axis varies but that's confuses me as it would result in bins gathering an "artificial" high number of observations. Not sure how histograms are typically displayed with log scale X axis. Note that `ggplot(d) + geom_histogram(aes(x = cMPerSite, y=bpInPiece), stat="identity")` does not display anything either so the problem is not only a question of log scale on the X-axis. In each bin of `cMPerSite`, the height of the bar should represent the total sum of `bpInPiece`. Did I more or less answer your questions?

Comment: How is this related to the [graph] tag? You realize that that tag is for mathematical graphs, not charts, right?

Comment: Actually the graph tag refers to graphics, charts and display of data.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started

Assuming your data is too large to process in one step - the idea is to manually generate a histogram, which is essentially the number of observations per bin

1) Split your data.frame to a size that's manageable for your memory - `N` can be any number

```
    N <- 10
    L <- split(df, cut(seq_len(nrow(df)), breaks=N))
```

2) For each split

- sum `bpInPiece` for each group - `{ i %>% group_by(G = floor(-log10(cMPerSite))) %>% summarise(sum=sum(bpInPiece)) }`
- Then aggregate all splits - `%>% group_by(G) %>% summarise(sum = sum(sum))`
- Then plot - `ggplot(...)`

  ```
  library(tidyverse)
  counts <- map_df(L, function(i) { i %>% group_by(G = floor(-log10(cMPerSite))) %>% summarise(sum=sum(bpInPiece)) }) %>%
               group_by(G) %>% summarise(sum = sum(sum)) %>%
               ggplot(., aes(G, sum)) + geom_col()
  counts
  ```